# Python PPTX module - Setting presentation to loop until Escape

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to set a .pptx presentation to loop until Escape is pressed. Usually this is done in Powerpoint in the Set up Slide Show Dialog, but I'm doing it with the python pptx module. I have tested with opc-diag and determined that the only difference when that option is selected is that there is a tag like this in the /ppt/presProps.xml part of the powerpoint file: `<p:showPr loop="1" showNarration="1">`

Now, in my python code, I have tried something to this extent with no success:

```
def xpath(el, query):
    nsmap = {'p': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main'}
    return etree.ElementBase.xpath(el, query, namespaces=nsmap)
    
presentation = Presentation()
p = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
ele = etree.Element(etree.QName(p, "showPr"), attrib={'loop': '1'})

# this does not work... Expecting element, getting presentation. 
xpath(presentation, './/p:presentationPr')[0].getparent().insert(-1, ele)
```

I need to append the element for showPr to the root element of the presentation, but the xpath function is expecting an element, where I have just the presentation being passed. I do not know how to access the root node to append the showPr loop bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried the above code, which I was expecting to produce my desired result of setting `<p:showPr loop="1" showNarration="1">` inside the /ppt/presProps.xml file but it is expecting an element, and I'm passing the presentation object. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are a few more steps:

1. You need to get the `PresentationProperties` "part", which is an XML document distinct from the `Presentation` part. (The files inside the .pptx zip archive are called *parts* in the OPC lingo.)

```py
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT

prs_part = presentation.part
prs_props_part = prs_part.part_related_by(RT.PML_PRES_PROPS)
```

2. You need to to get the root element of the prs_props part:

```py
from pptx.oxml import parse_xml

presentationPr = parse_xml(prs_props_part.blob)
```

Then you should be able to run your XPath expressions against that `presentationPr` element.

This should work to print the XML out to have a look at it, which will confirm the steps so far have worked:

```py
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import serialize_for_reading

print(serialize_for_reading(presentationPr))
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply and the great library! 

I've updated my code to the following:
```
def set_pres_repeat(pres):
    p = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
    ele = etree.Element(etree.QName(p, "showPr"), attrib={'loop': '1'})

    prs_part = pres.part
    prs_props_part = prs_part.part_related_by(RT.PRES_PROPS)
    presentationPr = parse_xml(prs_props_part.blob)

    print(serialize_for_reading(presentationPr))

    print(xpath(presentationPr, './/p:presentationPr'))
```
And while I do get the desired XML, the last print returns []

Comment: The `presentationPr` variable _is_ the `p:presentationPr` element. It does not contain such an element as a descendant, which is what your XPath expression is looking for. You want to change your XPath to something like `".//p:showPr"` or something else that shows up in the XML that is printed out. If you just want to unconditionally append the `p:showPr` element you can do that, but I'd look first to see if there's one there and then just edit it if found.

Comment: I don't think `presentation.part` is documented, by the way.

Comment: @MartinPacker I consider `presentation.part` an "internal" implementation detail, subject to change and all. Also, it's of no use to someone who isn't using internals to extend the package for some use-case. So I intentionally exclude it from the API documentation. Folks who are hacking with internals can easily find it in the code and it has a docstring like all the other methods which is what the documentation would say if it was there :)

Comment: Thanks @scanny. It wasn't a complaint. And I'm quite likely to use this in md2pptx (though I probably shouldn't unless I ride the tiger of python-pptx changes). 

Comment: @MartinPacker one place documenting that _would_ be good though is in the (aspirational) contributor notes. I'd love to get those more firmly developed to give a leg up to folks who do extension/workaround functions, which is a lot of us of course :)